# Android Google Maps Sign up not works and it says entered MD5 Certificate not valid

Tags: android

I generated md5 fingerprint correctly

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin>keytool.exe -list -ali
as androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -st
orepass android -keypass android
androiddebugkey, Nov 11, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
:**:**:**:**:**:**
```

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin>

but when I put it on https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

then it shows,

> The fingerprint that you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.

Comment: Your question title does not help you at all! Say something like Google,maps API. Sigup failure, for example

Comment: hey dude i can generate md5 fingerprint by debug.keystore but when i copy that md5 fingerprint on https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup page & click on api key generation then it shows this msg The fingerprint that you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint. plz dude i stuck plz help me fast

Answer (score 1):

In map API v2+ you need SHA1 fingerprint not md5

> You can discover the SHA1 fingerprint of your developer certificate
>   using the following command:
>   keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore